# Concordance in python. alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to write a concordance program where I am trying to have the shell open a file, read it, and interpret what the contents are. Then I want it to print out the words, in alphabetical order along with where the words are located in relation to the text. so far I have this:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    filename= input('what file? ')
    handle = open(filename, 'r')
elif sys.argv[1]  == '-':
    handle = sys.stdin
else:
    handle = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

appearances = []
position = 0
allwords = {}
for line in handle.readlines():
    words = line.split()
    for w in words:
        w = w.lower()
        if w in allwords.keys():
            allwords [w] += 1
        else:
            allwords[w] =1
        for w in allwords:
            if not w in allwords:
                allwords[w] = []
                appearances.append(position)
                position +=1
            else:
                appearances.append(position)
                position += 1   
handle.close()

keys = sorted(allwords.keys())
for k in keys:
    print('{:15s} {} {}'.format(k, appearances, position))
```

so far the code is giving me the words correctly in alphabetical order; however, it is not giving me the proper location of where the words are located. I am somewhat new to python so if you could try and keep it a little basic, it would be appreciated. I also want to keep in punctuation to make it a little more "unique."

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the line number corresponding to a word ?

Comment: So you want the words in the file, the number of times each word appears and the positions of each of the occurrences?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's unclear from your question what are you trying to achieve exactly. Please clarify your requirements and provide examples of the input and the output that you expect. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could understand, You are concerned about the actual position of words present in the file and at the same time you want the words to be printed in alphabetical order. You may use the following code:

*Note that we always will have a count for each word and which is the length of the list storing the positions of that particular word.*

```
# allwords is a dictionary which uses word as the key and the list of position of the word in the file as the value.
# The position will be recored as (line_number, word_number) tuple where word_number is position of the word in that particular line.

allwords = {}

# Get the index of the line as well.
for lineno,line in enumerate(handle.readlines()):

    words = line.split()

    # Get the word index as well.
    for wordno,w in enumerate(words):

        w = w.lower()

        # Make the position tuple and append in the list of appearances for that particular word.
        position = (lineno+1, wordno+1)

        if w not in allwords.keys():

            allwords[w] = []

        allwords[w].append(position)



for key in sorted(allwords.keys()):
    print(key + " appeared " + str(len(allwords[key])) + " number of times and positions are:")
    for tup in allwords[key]:
        print(tup)
```